# Using NSTimer, calling two functions with the same name, different parameters, both use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to write my own fade-ins and fade-outs using the AVAudioPlayer as a helper.

My problem is this: I have two method definitions with the same name, but one takes an int and the other takes no parameters.  Is there a way for me to tell NSTimer which one to call?  Couldn't really make sense of the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

```
-(void) stopWithFadeOut 
{
if (_player.volume > 0.1) {
    [self adjustVolume:-.1];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(stopWithFadeOut) userInfo:NULL repeats:NO];
}
else {
    [self stop];
}
}
```

and

```
-(void) stopWithFadeOut:(NSString *)speed 
{
int incr = [speed intValue];
if (_player.volume > 0.1) {
    [self adjustVolume:-incr];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(stopWithFadeOut) userInfo:NULL repeats:NO];
}
else {
    [self stop];
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those actually have *different* names. The colon is significant, so the name (and hence the argument to `@selector()`) of the second method is `stopWithFadeOut:`.*

To create the timer, then, you want:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(stopWithFadeOut:) 
                               userInfo:NULL                   //^ Note! Colon!
                                repeats:NO];
```

However, this method is incorrect, because an `NSTimer` passes *itself* to its action method; it's not possible for you to *pass in* an arbitrary object. This is what the `userInfo:` parameter is for. You can sort of *attach* some object to the timer, and retrieve it inside the action method using the `userInfo` method, like so:

```
- (void)stopWithFadeOut: (NSTimer *)tim 
{
    NSString * speed = [tim userInfo];
    int incr = [speed intValue];
    if (_player.volume > 0.1) {
        [self adjustVolume:-incr];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(stopWithFadeOut:) 
                                       userInfo:speed
                                        repeats:NO];
    }
```

(Also note that this means your first method isn't really a correct `NSTimer` action method, because it doesn't have the `NSTimer` parameter.)

---

*The compiler wouldn't have let you declare or define two methods with the same name in one class, and the parameter type doesn't count as part of the selector, so trying to create `-(void)dumblethwaite:(int)circumstance;` and `-(void)dumblethwaite:(NSString *)jinxopotamus;` in one class doesn't work.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that userInfo is an id, so you can't just pass an int. (Well, you can just cast it, and deal with the 32-/64-bit issues, and pay attention to retain issues, etc., but you shouldn't…) Also, the original version (and therefore your example) would probably do better to wrap the int in an NSNumber instead of an NSString. But other than these minor quibbles, this answer is perfect.

Comment: @abarnert: There's no `int` being passed in the question (or my answer), just an `NSString` whose `intValue` is used.

Comment: The point is that the "incr" value you want to get into the timer callback is clearly an int. For this particular case, since the int happens to be wrapped in a string anyway, there's no issue. But you can't count on things working out that way in general. And I think the answer, especially with the dumblethwaite:(int) comment, might confuse a newbie ObjC user into thinking they can pass any parameter they want as userInfo and get it in their callback.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with.  Thanks Josh.

```
-(void) pauseWithFadeOut
{
NSNumber *incr = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.1];
while (_player.volume > 0.1) {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(fadeOut) userInfo:incr repeats:NO];
}
}
-(void)fadeOut: (NSTimer*) deleg
{   
int incr = (int) [deleg userInfo];
if (_player.volume > 0.1) {
    [self adjustVolume:-incr];
}

} 
-(void) pauseWithFadeOut:(NSString *)speed
{
NSNumber *incr = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:[speed floatValue]];
while (_player.volume > 0.1) {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(fadeOut) userInfo:incr repeats:NO];
}

[self pause];

}
-(void) stopWithFadeOut
{
NSNumber *incr = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.1];
while (_player.volume > 0.1) {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(fadeOut) userInfo:incr repeats:NO];
}
}
-(void) stopWithFadeOut:(NSString *)speed
{
NSNumber *incr = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:[speed floatValue]];
while (_player.volume > 0.1) {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(fadeOut) userInfo:incr repeats:NO];
}

[self stop];

}
```